# Reptilian world about to be destroyed

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm searching for a sci-Fi novel, where a young reptile scientist finds out the world is slowly being destroyed by the gravitational pull of the planet their world revolves around. It is causing earthquakes that are getting rapidly worse. He also discovers that the priest eat seven of eight hatchings to control the over population. He uncovers that the queen is the only one allowed to have all eight children, one becoming the ruler and the other seven becoming rulers of other nations, thus preventing wars. Now the young dinosaur-like scientist must find a way off their world before the quakes destroy it.

Comment: When did you read (?) it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is the [Quintaglio Ascension trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintaglio_Ascension_Trilogy) by Robert J Sawyer. It has sentient Tyrannosauruses, a planet falling apart due to gravitational forces, and 7 of 8 young being killed by priests. The initial protagonist is a scientist who first realizes that their world is too close to the gas giant it orbits and will be torn apart by tidal forces.